# Creating a Custom Post Type as a Plugin? Why?

Tags: custom-post-types, plugin-development

I've been experimenting with creating a Custom Post Type as a plugin (because I've seen this recommended in various places).

But I have a question **not about the how**, but rather ***the why*** of building CPT's as a plugin.

**Yes...** Adding the CPT as a plugin does keep my functions.php nice and tidy.

**But...**

1. Assuming I've enabled `has_archive` I still need to create `archive-cpt.php`, right?
2. Also: In order to display the CPT I need to create a custom loop, so I still need to create `single-cpt.php` ...right?
3. And these files need to be created ***in the theme***, right?

If I understand this correctly,

1. **If I disable the plugin:** I ***still*** have to remove (or hide or something) the `archive-cpt.php` and `single-cpt.php` pages.
2. **If I switch Themes**: I still have to add those two pages into the new theme. Right?

I haven't even touched the issue of adding a CPT to the default loop (and it's implications on plugin-based cpt's).

So, why a CPT ***plugin?***

Comment: Of course, after writing this question I saw [this post](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/88371/how-do-you-create-an-archive-for-a-custom-post-type-from-a-plugin?rq=1). But I'm still not sure. Is the selected answer considered a "Best Practice"? Please advise.

Comment: you don't *need* templates specific to single and archive cpt views, only if you want them presented differently than the single and archive templates your theme falls back to, which may just be index.php in some cases.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

toscho's answer is correct as to the technical reasons to define your CPT in a plugin, but it seems to me that much of you question stems from a misunderstanding of the template hierarchy. Almost, but not quite, every template file that you've seen is optional.

> With the exception of the basic index.php template file, Theme
>   developers can choose whether they want to implement a particular
>   template file or not. If WordPress cannot find a template file with a
>   matching name, it skips down to the next file name in the hierarchy.
>   If WordPress cannot find any matching template file, index.php (the
>   Theme's home page template file) will be used.
>
> http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy

WordPress will use the particular specialized files if they exist but fall-back to another file-- ultimately `index.php`-- if there are no specialized files. Your theme does not have to implement anything special to deal with or compensate for your plugin's CPT's. The theme *can* but does not *have to*.

> 1. Assuming I've enabled `has_archive` I still need to create `archive-cpt.php`, right?

No. `archive.php` will be used and if that fails then `index.php`

> 1. Also: In order to display the CPT I need to create a custom loop, so I still need to create `single-cpt.php` ...right?

Again, no. Same reason. `single.php` will be used and if not `index.php`.

> 1. And these files need to be created ***in the theme***, right?

Yes, but they are optional. You don't need them at all.

> 1. **If I disable the plugin:** I ***still*** have to remove (or hide or something) the `archive-cpt.php` and `single-cpt.php` pages.

No. You don't need to do anything. The templates will not be used.

> 1. **If I switch Themes**: I still have to add those two pages into the new theme. Right?

Wrong. The templates are optional. You only need them if you want a customized display for the post type.

When you understand that the theme and the CPT are not as intimately connected as your question make it seem, then some of the other logic should make a bit more sense.

Comment: OK. Now I get it.

Answer (score 3):

The theme isn’t loaded when the constant `SHORTINIT` is set to `TRUE` (custom AJAX handlers, importers or APIs), no posts can be added to such a custom post type or taxonomy then.

The templates are the *views* for the custom content, they should not define or rely on the logic.

Also, after a theme switch, the user cannot access and change the post type content anymore, because there would be no interface without the registration.

After disabling a *plugin* you don’t have to change the theme. The templates are just not used anymore.

*Update:* Another advantage of plugins is the ability to activate them **network wide**. I am the main developer for [Multilingual Press](http://marketpress.com/product/multilingual-press-pro/), and we offer our users a feature to translate and connect custom post type posts. But this cannot work if they are bound to a theme, because a theme is always active *per site,* not across the whole network. Theme post types are really hard to translate.

See also: [Where to put my code: plugin or functions.php?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/73031/where-to-put-my-code-plugin-or-functions-php)

Comment: _"The theme isn’t loaded when the constant SHORTINIT is set to TRUE (custom AJAX handlers, importers or APIs), no posts can be added to such a custom post type or taxonomy."_  ??? I have no idea what that means (yet). I'm just getting into CPT's. Please explain.

Comment: "Where to put my code: plugin or functions.php?" - Excellent discussion. Seems I've stumbled into a Hornet's Nest.

Comment: Ok, so no "simple" answer to this question, eh? The link seems to provide the best info on how to "decide" where to put the CPT (based on several variables).

Comment: The simple answer is: Custom post types work better in plugins.