# Maintain custom post types and taxonomies in all themes

Tags: plugins, custom-post-types, plugin-development, custom-taxonomy, taxonomy

When I change the theme in dashboard, activated plugins that use custom post types, stay in the menu. But my own custom post types that I created myself disappear. Logically, It is because I create custom post types (and taxonomies) in `functions.php` of the current theme.

For reference I use the code below:

```
function post_type_aya_bi_aya() {
    $labels = array(
            //...
    );
    $args = array(
        'labels'        => $labels,
        'public'        => true,

    );
    register_post_type( 'aya-bi-aya', $args );  
}

add_action( 'init', 'post_type_aya_bi_aya' );

function taxonomy_aya_bi_aya() {
    $labels = array(
           //..
    );
    $args = array(
        'labels' => $labels,
        'hierarchical' => true,
        'public' => TRUE, 
        'show_ui' => TRUE,
        'query_var' => 'sowar', 
    );
    register_taxonomy( 'sowar', 'aya-bi-aya', $args );
}
add_action( 'init', 'taxonomy_aya_bi_aya', 0 );
```

**My question is:** What is the best way to maintain custom post types after change of the theme. Do I need to create a plugin responsabile of creating them, or do I need in addition to execute some functions? If else, if you have a better approach, I thank you very much for your valuable time.

Comment: See [Where to put my code: plugin or functions.php?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/73031/where-to-put-my-code-plugin-or-functions-php) and [Creating a Custom Post Type as a Plugin? Why?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/99138/creating-a-custom-post-type-as-a-plugin-why)

Comment: From titles, it looks perfect. I feel your links are important. thank you in advance.

Comment: I think this question should be closed as a duplicate of the last linked. Any objections?

Comment: I am totally agreeing with you.